# Console and NTVDM resolution upscaling in full-screen

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, console, ntvdm

When running either console Windows applications (such as [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/index.php?l=en)) or legacy DOS applications via [NTVDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine#Windows_NTVDM) in the full-screen mode, I observe my Nvidia graphics driver upscaling the display resolution to that of my Windows desktop (`1600x1200`).

For DOS applications, this can be remedied by switching desktop resolution to the application resolution (provided it is at least `640x480`) *before* running the application.

This doesn't work for console applications, however, since a `9x16` font at `80x25` char cells yields a non-standard resolution of `720x400`, and obviously I can't set my desktop to that (despite it has been supported by most displays for ages).

The problem is specific to *Windows XP* (and maybe to some extent *Vista*), as *Windows 7* and above no longer supports full-screen mode for console applications.

How can I entirely disable upscaling for my graphics card driver?

Comment: May be DosBox will be suitable for you?

Comment: @Maximus For *DOS* applications, yes. But what about *Windows* console applications? Rebooting into safe mode to get a plain non-accelerated VESA is not an option.

Comment: Check if the options are useful in right-click on the `.exe` > Properties > Compatibility tab.

Comment: Did you check ?

Comment: @harrymc No, not yet. Thank you for your suggestion. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: What's the point in setting up a bounty and then abandoning your post?